# Attaching multiple PDFs from selected folder to email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to allow users to select the folder where they have kept multiple PDFs and extract them.

Unless I put the specific pathname, I am unable to get the macro to run correctly.

This works, if instead of referencing the function I reference the specific pathname:

```
StrPath = "C:\Users\Mark\OneDrive - Corporation\Desktop\Work file\RemA\Canada\"
```

My full code, which does not attach any PDFs:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Function selectfolder()

'Defining the Variables
Dim user_name As String 'sequence of characters: alphabets, numbers, special characters
user_name = Environ("username") 'to pick up the username from work environment

'Prompt for folder creation
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker) 'standard wording
    .Title = "Select the folder to save"
    .InitialFileName = "C:\Users\" & user_name & "\OneDrive - Corporation\Desktop\Work file" 'base directory to open
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Function 'if user does not press OK, end the function'
    selectfolder = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

End Function

Sub sendremindermail()

'Defining the Variables
Dim outlookapp As Object
Dim outlookmailitem As Object
Dim myattachments As Object
Dim StrPath As String
Dim StrFile As String
Dim network, Fldr As String

'If user does not choose a folder
StrPath = selectfolder()
If StrPath = "" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Set outlookapp = CreateObject("outlook.application")
Set outlookmailitem = outlookapp.createitem(0)
Set myattachments = outlookmailitem.Attachments

'Creating the email and adding attachment
With outlookmailitem
    'Title of the Email
    .Subject = "Test Run"
    'To be sent to recipients
    .To = "ABCD@gmail.com"
    'Body of the email
    .Body = "Dear " & ActiveSheet.Range("C6").Value & ","
    .Body = .Body & "Please find attached your Finance Report for the month of " & Format(Range("C8"), "mmmm yyyy") & "."

    'Attach your files
    StrFile = Dir(StrPath & "*.pdf")
    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
        myattachments.Add StrPath & StrFile
        StrFile = Dir
    Loop
   
    'Displaying only the email. Not sending
    .Display
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function selectfolder returns the path without the '' at the end, so please add '' at the end, so selectfolder has to return like "c:\temp\pdffolder', currently it is returning 'c:\temp\pdffolder', so Dir line is not returning the files.

Comment: c:\temp\pdffolder to  c:\temp\pdffolder\

Comment: \ is missing in my comment

Comment: '' is '\', its weird, slash is missing within the single quote in my comment

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Where do I add the \"  ? is it .InitialFileName?

Comment: selectfolder = .SelectedItems(1) in this line 

or

StrFile = Dir(StrPath & "\"  & "*.pdf") in this line